# Как отменить создание дополнительной картинки в webpack 5?

Tags: javascript, webpack, frontend, sass

Всем привет.
У меня такая история: взял я одну сборку webpack и начал переписывать под себя как тут выскочила но не ошибка,баг - одним словом: в новой версии webpack вместо `url-loader`, `raw-loader` и `file-loader` стали использовать `asset`, `asset/resource`, `asset/inline`, `asset/source`. Теперь я обрабатываю картинки через `type: 'asset/resource'`. Все было хорошо пока я не написал в стилях `background: url('~/assets/images/promo.jpg')` и теперь когда запущу `build` сборку в папке `dist`появляеться картинка и её имя в виде хеша. Изменить её имя у меня получилось добавив после поля `type: 'asset/resource'` `generate: { [name][ext] }` можно ещё перед именем написать папку и картинка будет создаваться в неё но это проблемы не решает ведь если я укажу сохранять в папку с картинками, то тогда будет конфликт двух одинаковых картинок и проект не соберётся. Мне не нужно чтобы `webpack` создавал новую картинку, я хочу чтобы он брал ту которую я перенес вместе с папкой `img` с помощью `copy-webpack-plugin`.
Как решить эту проблему я не знаю, надеюсь здесь мне помогут.
Вот [git repo](https://github.com/SergeiWeb/webpack-5) со сборкой.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья если кто-то столкнется с данной проблемой, просто вместо новых `asset modules` `webpack 5` используйте старые `file-loader`, `url-loader` и `raw-loader`. Ведь они не будут насильно создавать новую картинку если у тебя есть такая же.